Laravel is experiencing an issue with the custom data field type in a PostgreSQL
I have an existing PostgreSQL database and I want to use Laravel Backpack to create CRUD routes for it. However, I am encountering an issue with the custom data type of certain fields.
For example, the "role" field in the user table has a custom data type called "Type".
I am encountering the following error:
"Unknown database type 'roles' requested. Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\PostgreSQL100Platform may not support it."

How can I fix this issue?
